# How to: add custom format for logging in Laravel 3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am using Laravel 3.2.13, I don't want to show errors to my users so I hide them and set:

**/config/error.php**

```
'log' => true
```

The log is working but it is not very readable, I would like to add some custom information like the current page `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or the session user_id `Session::get('id')`.

Where can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do that in Laravel 3.2.13 without touching the source is by *listen to the event `laravel.log`*:

```
Event::listen('laravel.log', function($type, $message)
{
    $message = $type.' ['.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'] '.$message;
    File::append(path('storage').'logs/'.date('Y-m-d').'.log', $message);
});
```

Note that when listening to this event it will prevent from Laravel's log to write the line to the file, so you are aware of if.

For more information check the source of [Log.php for Laravel 3.2.13](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v3.2.13/laravel/log.php#L54)

Comment: Perfect, i juste made some adjust for get the same look at the original http://paste.laravel.com/vIZ , thanks.